# Get motherday date in format dd.mm.yyyy

Tags: javascript, date

I've tried to get the mother day date (first sunday of may) by Javascript. But the result of my code is 0.4.2021. Where is the fault or there a much more simplier way to get the mothers day date (dd.mm.yyyy) (german time zone).

```js
var currentYear = new Date().getFullYear()
var mayFirst = new Date(currentYear + '-05-01');
var dayOfWeek = mayFirst.getUTCDay();
var firstSunday;
if (dayOfWeek === 0) {
    firstSunday = mayFirst;
} else {
    firstSunday = new Date();
    firstSunday.setDate(1 + (7 - dayOfWeek));
}
var mothersDay = new Date(firstSunday);
mothersDay.setDate(firstSunday.getUTCDate() + 7);
mothersDay = new Date(mothersDay);

console.log(mothersDay.getDay() + "." + mothersDay.getMonth() + "." + mothersDay.getFullYear());
```

Comment: Month in javascript is zero based (Yes, you read that right!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the proper way of doing this, without error-prone calculations or string concatenation, including formatting it as DD.MM.YYYY:

```js
// Mother's Day is the second sunday in May
const d = new Date();
d.setMonth(4); // May
d.setDate(8); // May 8 is the earliest possible date
// while not a sunday, move to next day 
while (d.getUTCDay()) d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);

const result = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('de-DE', { day: "2-digit", month: "2-digit", year: "numeric"}).format(d);

document.body.innerHTML += result;
```

Comment: You could calculate the offset needed to get to next Sunday `(7 - d.getUTCDay()) % 7` and add this instead of testing each day.

Comment: @phuzi Yeah, I was debating whether to use that method but wanted to keep my code as readable as possible :)

Answer (score 1):

`getMonth()` is `0` based so you need to add 1 to that. Also you want to use `getDate()` instead of `getDay()` to get the day value of the date.

I assume you want to get the 2nd sunday of may since the line below from your code adds 7 days. If you want the first sunday you should remove this line too.

`mothersDay.setDate(firstSunday.getUTCDate() + 7);`

```js
var currentYear = new Date().getFullYear()
var mayFirst = new Date(currentYear + '-05-01');
var dayOfWeek = mayFirst.getUTCDay();
var firstSunday;
if (dayOfWeek === 0) {
    firstSunday = mayFirst;
} else {
    firstSunday = new Date();
    firstSunday.setDate(1 + (7 - dayOfWeek));
}
var mothersDay = new Date(firstSunday);
mothersDay.setDate(firstSunday.getUTCDate() + 7);

mothersDay = new Date(mothersDay);

console.log(mothersDay.getDate() + "." + (mothersDay.getMonth() + 1) + "." + mothersDay.getFullYear());
```